# What does the ".git" mean in a git URL?

Tags: git

I setup a git repo in foo

```
cd
mkdir foo
cd foo
git init
```

Now I want to reference that remotely

```
git clone git+ssh://me@somemachine/home/me/foo.git

fatal: git remote error '/home/me/foo.git' does not appear to be a git repository
```

So I take .git off and it works. But nearly every example I see has ".git" at the end. What does that ".git" mean?

Also, what's the difference between ssh://... and git+ssh://... (in both meaning and practical terms)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do some repository URLs end in .git while others don't?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11068576/why-do-some-repository-urls-end-in-git-while-others-dont) (which was asked later, but has a better answer).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### What does that ".git" mean?

`.git` at the end of a git repository folder is just a naming convention that usually means that the folder is a server and not a client. I believe it's determined by the repository being bare or not (bare repositories have no working directory). The clone URL just points to a folder, if the actual folder has .git at the end, add it. Otherwise, don't.

### Also, what's the difference between ssh://... and git+ssh://... (in both meaning and practical terms)

In practical terms they're pretty much the same. In meaning, they're using different protocols to connect to the server. `ssh://` opens up an SSH connection to a server with a specific user and runs the git commands on the server (typically the server will restrict the commands by setting the user's shell to `/usr/bin/git-shell`). `git+ssh://` means that the server is running `git daemon` locally and that clients need to first open an SSH connection to interact with the daemon.

Comment: Also as a small note, `git+ssh://` is hardly ever used, and according to other answers, has been deprecated and removed from current versions of git.

Comment: the folder is a server and not a client...what?!

Comment: I believe what I meant was that it's a bare copy of the repo with the sole purpose of sharing (in the more centralized server/client setup that git is now almost exclusively used in), as opposed to a network of people with a checked out repo that are configured with each other as remotes (where the folder name typically does not end with ".git")

Comment: Looking at my currently checked out repos with default settings, the .git suffix is stripped during a clone on Windows with git 2.12.2.windows.2 and on Ubuntu with git 2.7.4. By that I mean a repo in the form `https://github.com/foo/bar.git` when cloned in `~` will make the directory `~/bar/` and not `~/bar.git/`. I've observed this behavior from Github, Gitlab, and BitBucket, if this happens to be something that the server controls

Answer (score 7):

It's a common (but certainly not universal) convention that bare git repositories are created in directories whose names end with `.git`. That's the reason that you usually see `.git` at the end of repository URLs.

I'm not sure about the `git+ssh` scheme - in fact I can't find a reference to it in the git man pages. According to the [Eclipse forums](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/629741/) the protocol has been removed in favor of plain old `ssh`. (The Eclipse forums are of course not an official source of information about git, but that would make sense. I never knew what the difference was supposed to be anyway.)

Answer (score 3):

The `.git` suffix is just convention to indicate that the directory in question is a bare git repository (ie, one in which there is no working copy). It's not actually required.

As for `git+ssh://`, according to [the git-fetch manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-fetch), it is not allowed:

> Git natively supports ssh, git, http, https, ftp, ftps, and rsync protocols. The following syntaxes may be used with them:
>
> - ssh://[user@]host.xz[:port]/path/to/repo.git/
> - git://host.xz[:port]/path/to/repo.git/
> - http[s]://host.xz[:port]/path/to/repo.git/
> - ftp[s]://host.xz[:port]/path/to/repo.git/
> - rsync://host.xz/path/to/repo.git/
>
>   An alternative scp-like syntax may also be used with the ssh protocol:>
> - [user@]host.xz:path/to/repo.git/

Answer (score 0):

.git has no special meanings, weather you need to add it depends where the repo is located on server side, with or without .git.

sometimes a repo with .git imply it is a bare repo.