# Local Git Remotes: To “…/.git” or not to “…/.git”?

Tags: git, url, version-control

When adding a remote (or closing) from another local git repository, is there a functional difference between pointing at the ‘`.git`’ directory inside the working copy and pointing at the just working copy?

*I.E. Is there any difference in how fetching/pushing/pulling from within ‘a-repo’ will work, ‘a-repo’ is cloned with:*

```
git clone ~/Projects/some-old-repo/.git ~/Desktop/a-repo
```

vs.

```
git clone ~/Projects/some-old-repo ~/Desktop/a-repo
```

Comment: Meh? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8686691/what-does-the-git-mean-in-a-git-url

Comment: I'm pretty sure that your second form resolves to the first form internally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say that there is no difference. Typically when you clone a bare repository, the working copy is empty, and nethertheless, the result of the cloning is the same whatever you point on the .git folder or the directory containing the .git folder...

Comment: It looks like you are correct, kind sir. I've been testing this out myself a bit more as of recent, and it seems functionality is identical in every way (as @Kevin Ballard suggested above). Thank you both for your insight!